# How to print git history in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, git, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing an analysis report with rmarkdown and would like to have a "document versions" section in which I would indicate the different versions of the document and the changes made.

Instead of writing it down manually, I was thinking about using git history and inserting it automatically in the markdown document (formatting it in a table).

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install `git2r`, https://github.com/ropensci/git2r then you can do stuff like:

```
> r = repository(".")
> cs = commits(r)
> cs[[1]]
[02cf9a0] 2017-02-02: uses Rcpp attributes instead of inline
```

So now I have a list of all the commits on this repo. You can get the info out of each commit and format as per your desire into your document.

```
> summary(cs[[1]])
Commit:  02cf9a0ff92d3f925b68853374640596530c90b5
Author:  barryrowlingson <b.rowlingson@gmail.com>
When:    2017-02-02 23:03:17

     uses Rcpp attributes instead of inline

11 files changed, 308 insertions, 151 deletions
DESCRIPTION           | -  0 +  2  in 2 hunks
NAMESPACE             | -  0 +  2  in 1 hunk
R/RcppExports.R       | -  0 + 23  in 1 hunk
R/auxfunctions.R      | -  1 +  1  in 1 hunk
R/skewt.r             | -  0 +  3  in 1 hunk
R/update_params.R     | -  1 +  1  in 1 hunk
R/update_params_cpp.R | -149 +  4  in 2 hunks
src/.gitignore        | -  0 +  3  in 1 hunk
src/RcppExports.cpp   | -  0 + 76  in 1 hunk
src/hello_world.cpp   | -  0 + 13  in 1 hunk
src/update_params.cpp | -  0 +180  in 1 hunk
```

So if you just want the time and the commit message then you can grab it out of the object.

```
> cs[[3]]@message
[1] "fix imports etc\n"
> cs[[3]]@committer@when
2017-01-20 23:26:20
```

I don't know if there's proper accessor functions for these rather than using @-notation to get slots. Need to read the docs a bit more...

You can make a data frame from your commits this way:

```
> do.call(rbind,lapply(cs,function(cs){as(cs,"data.frame")}))
```

which converts the dates to POSIXct objects, which is nice. Creating a markdown table from the data frame should be trivial!

Answer (score 3):

You can manually convert git log to markdown with `pretty=format` [1]

Something like

```
git log --reverse --pretty=format:'| %H | %s |'
```

This will output something like this:

```
| a8d5defb511f1e44ddea21b42aec9b03ee768253 | initial commit |
| fdd9865e9cf01bd53c4f1dc106ee603b0a730f48 | fix tests |
| 10b58e8dd9cf0b9bebbb520408f0b342df613627 | add Dockerfile |
| d039004e8073a20b5d6eab1979c1afa213b78fa3 | update README.md |
```

1: https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Comment: That's a good idea, but it's not called from my rmarkdown document and I would like it to be done automatically when I generate my vignette

Comment: You'd have to call it via a shell escape and `system` from R, capturing the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --pretty=format:"## %h %n- **Author:** %an %n- **Date:** %ad %n- **Message:** %s%n" --date=short
```